# Vim puts a lot of tab characters when pasting code from clipboard

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I copied the code from [github](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) page. When i pasted it on my vim editor, it puts four `tab characters` for every indented block. It looks like this,
[image]

All tab characters are printed as `^I` because of `set list` in .vimrc.
my .vimrc looks like this,

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set nocompatible
set smartindent
set tabstop=2
set list
set tags=~/pytags
set statusline+=%F
```

Answer (score 9):

Vim is trying to format your code as you paste. Use paste mode before pasting anything into vim

```
:set paste
```

Paste your contents, then unset it

```
:set nopaste
```